# how to get value every day of month with mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, statistics

i have column details

```
Create table details(
    Id [nvarchar](255) primary key
    CurrentValue smallint,
    CreateAt DateTime
)

CREATE TABLE Dates (
  d DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (d)
)
DECLARE @dIncr DATE = '2000-01-01'
DECLARE @dEnd DATE = '2100-01-01'

WHILE ( @dIncr < @dEnd )
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Dates (d) VALUES( @dIncr )
  SELECT @dIncr = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @dIncr )
END
```

i want to get the column Current value with from date and to date, but sometimes the current value isn't entered every day, so i want to get every day of from date and to date.

here is my query :

```
select 
AVG(rd1.CurrentValue)
from details
left join Dates as c  ON c.d BETWEEN '07-01-2018' AND '07-29-2018'
GROUP BY c.d
order by c.d
```

i don't know how to do this

And How to average that

the data i expect :

```
         Date  CurrentValue
    ========= =======
     1/2/2009    1500
     2/2/2009    2300
     3/2/2009     300
     4/2/2009    2200
     5/2/2009    0
    ...
    30/2/2009    1500
    etc.
```

Comment: You create a table called `DETAILS` with a column called `currentvalue` but your query references a table called `RoundDetails` and a column called `CurrentWeight`

Comment: oh sorry i wrong the name,

Comment: but i can not  join two table

Comment: Can you supply some sample data for your table `details` and your expected results?

Comment: ok wait me a sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `join` from your 'Dates' table to your `Details` table, rather than the other way around.  In this manner, you get all `Dates` values as well as any `Details` values that match:

```
select c.d
      ,avg(rd1.CurrentValue) as AverageValue
from Dates as c
    left join details as d
        on c.d = d.CreateAt
where c.d between '07-01-2018' and '07-29-2018'
group by c.d
order by c.d
```

Comment: can i ask you one more question. if my details table have relationship with other table (one to many `user`-`detail`) so how to join 3 columns user- details-calendar.
like user have how many details in this month

Comment: @beginerdeveloper: adding c.d to the selected columns and switching from LEFT to RIGHT join should have done the same

Comment: @PabloHenkowski  Yes, you are right.  But adding `right joins` into scripts, in my opinion, adds complexity that makes reading the script and understanding what it does more difficult.

Comment: @beginerdeveloper  Please do not ask additional questions in comments.  If you have a further requirement beyond your question here, as another question showing what you have tried and the difficulties you are facing.

Comment: @iamdave ok i got it

Answer (score 1):

Change you LEFT JOIN to

```
left join Dates as c  ON C.d = rd1.CreateAt
                        AND c.d BETWEEN '07-01-2018' AND '07-29-2018'
```

Comment: sorry i get this error when i apply your left join
`Column 'details.CurrentWeight' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: This is what I highlighted in an earlier comment.  You table definitions and queries reference different things.  `CurrentWeight` doesn't exist in the `details` table

Comment: yes i use this name in my local database, it is same

Answer (score 1):

1. `date` tables contain only date ranges and no gap, is this right?
2. what is column `d` on table date?
3. `currentvalue` or `CurrentWeight` ? why in your Code it is `CurrentValue` but the error is `CurrentWeight` ?

Try to use this code, I assume column `d` is date from table `date`.

`date` Table will be the main table because the date have no gaps so change it to right join. We will only take data from table details if it have any, so use ISNULL to set the empty data to zero when using average.

```
select c.d as [Date],
AVG(ISNULL(rd1.CurrentValue,0)) as [CurrentValue]
from details
right join Dates as c  ON c.d BETWEEN '07-01-2018' AND '07-29-2018'
GROUP BY c.d
order by c.d
```

Comment: currentvalue and CurrentWeight is same i use currentWeight in my local database, yes column d is date in table Dates